# What's the reverse DNS command line utility?

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system, command-line-interface, reverse-dns

What's the command to find the name of a computer given its IP address?

I always forget what this command is, but I know it exists in Windows and I assume it exists on the *nix command-line.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The commands [`dig`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) and [`host`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/host) should be what you're looking for ;)

On *nix systems, you can use this command:

```
dig -x [address]
```

Alternatively, you can add `+short` at the end of the `dig` command to output only the DNS result.

There's also [`nslookup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup) on both *nix and Windows systems for reverse DNS requests.

Comment: The same syntax also works with the `drill` utility from ldns, i.e. `drill -x 123.123.123.123`

Answer (score 75):

On *nix you can use:

```
dig -x [address]
```

Comment: This definitely seems to be the easiest way. Add +short at the end to return nothing but the rdns result. `dig -x [address] +short`

Comment: That `+short` flag is really useful!

Comment: Does this work with IPv6 addresses?

Comment: @ColinM Good point. I've edited my answer based on this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @Geremia, according to `man dig`, _The addr is an IPv4 address in dotted-decimal notation, or a colon-delimited IPv6 address._

Answer (score 21):

## Try "host"

- Forward lookup with [`host`](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/jump?q=host):

  ```
  $ host google-public-dns-b.google.com.
  google-public-dns-b.google.com has address 8.8.4.4
  google-public-dns-b.google.com has IPv6 address 2001:4860:4860::8844
  ```
- Reverse lookup with `host`:

  ```
  $ host 8.8.4.4
  4.4.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-public-dns-b.google.com.
  ```

### Similar to dig

- Forward lookup with [`dig`](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/jump?q=dig):

  ```
  $ dig google-public-dns-b.google.com. +short
  8.8.4.4
  ```
- Reverse lookup with `dig`:

  ```
  $ dig -x 8.8.4.4 +short
  google-public-dns-b.google.com.
  ```

BTW: `dig` is picky about its command line options ordering:

- `dig -x 8.8.4.4 +short` works.
- `dig +short -x 8.8.4.4` works.
- `dig -x +short 8.8.4.4` does not work.

## Try "rdt"

It takes a little more setup. But if you do this, then you can run this "rdt" PHP script from the command line and it's quite wonderful. It does a few back and forth trips between forward and reverse lookups.

Download from here: https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/net/rdt

Example. This is what it looks like when it's working:

```
$ rdt google-public-dns-b.google.com.
google-public-dns-b.google.com. = 2001:4860:4860::8844, 8.8.4.4
   2001:4860:4860::8844 = dns.google
      dns.google = 2001:4860:4860::8844, 2001:4860:4860::8888, 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8
         2001:4860:4860::8888 = dns.google
         8.8.8.8 = dns.google
   8.8.4.4 = dns.google
```

Answer (score 11):

On most of the Linux systems that I am aware of you can use:

```
 nslookup <ip-number EX: 127.0.0.1>
```

will work on the command line.

Come to think of it, isn't nslookup available on Windows XP?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And in previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Works on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 4):

I'm well aware that dig/host/nslookup are the standard tools for these, but I keep these around for testing the OS's resolution (essentially, to test nsswitch.conf is working correctly):

**gethostbyname:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Socket;

my @t = gethostbyname($ARGV[0]);
print "\$name     = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);
print "\$aliases  = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);
print "\$addrtype = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);
print "\$length   = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);

foreach (@t) {
  print "          = ", inet_ntoa($_), "\n";
}
```

**gethostbyaddr:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Socket;

my @t = gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($ARGV[0]), AF_INET);
print "\$name     = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);
print "\$aliases  = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);
print "\$addrtype = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);
print "\$length   = $t[0]\n"; shift(@t);

foreach (@t) {
  print "          = ", inet_ntoa($_), "\n";
}
```

example:

```
g3 0 /home/jj33/swap > gethostbyname www.google.com
$name     = www.l.google.com
$aliases  = www.google.com
$addrtype = 2
$length   = 4
          = 72.14.205.147
          = 72.14.205.103
          = 72.14.205.104
          = 72.14.205.99
g3 0 /home/jj33/swap > gethostbyaddr 72.14.205.147 
$name     = qb-in-f147.google.com
$aliases  = 
$addrtype = 2
$length   = 4
          = 72.14.205.147
```

Comment: you can do "getent hosts [IP or HOSTNAME]"

Comment: Hmmm...  I wrote the tools originally just to play with the functions, so no loss there but I certainly wouldn't have pasted them into serverfault if I had known about the getent tool.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: -1: they are limited to IPv4, gethostbyname does not retrieve IPv6 addresses when they exist and gethostbyaddr does not accept IPv6 addresses.

Comment: These functions are many years obsolete. They were even obsolete when this was written. In perl and most other languages you should be using getaddrinfo and getnameinfo.

Answer (score 4):

This question already has a million answers, but I'm gonna add another one. Here's a little function I wrote for easily doing reverse DNS with dig. Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file, reload your shell, and then you can do reverse DNS lookups with `revdns 1.2.3.4`:

```
function revdns() {
    octets=""
    addr="in-addr.arpa"

    # split the IP address into an array of octets
    IFS="." read -r -a octets <<< "$1"

    # add each octet to our $addr string in reverse order
    for octet in "${octets[@]}"; do
         addr=$octet"."$addr
    done

    # run a DNS pointer lookup with dig
    # `+short` makes dig's output very terse (un-verbose)
    # `"${@:2}"` passes any extra params from this command to dig
    dig ptr +short $addr "${@:2}"
}
```

Reverse DNS lookups are done by checking the pointer (PTR) records. If you wanna do reverse DNS for "1.2.3.4", you have to lookup pointer records for "4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa". My function takes in an IP address, reverses the order of the octets (i.e. changes it from 1.2.3.4 to 4.3.2.1), and then uses `dig` to execute the PTR lookup I just described.

You can, of course, just use `nslookup 1.2.3.4` if you have it, but I prefer this dig-based solution because it uses the OS' DNS servers instead of nslookup-provided ones (if you want, by the way, you can add additional dig flags when you call `revdns`, and they will get passed to dig)

Comment: According to its help `dig -x dot-notation` is the "shortcut for reverse lookups". I was wondering what the long version would be. Thanks for explaining! :)

Comment: from `man dig`:   _When the -x is used, there is no need to provide the name, class and type arguments.  dig automatically performs a lookup for a name like 94.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa and sets the query type and class to PTR and IN respectively._

Answer (score 3):

On Windows I got in to the habit of using:

```
ping -a <ip address>
```

as this will also reflect data from your `hosts` file and WINS and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using nslookup it's this (assuming 192.168.0.1 as the IP in question)

```
> set type=ptr
> 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

**EDIT:**
Remember a reverse lookup only works if there is a PTR record created for the IP, and it's not guaranteed to return the hostname you're looking for.  Completely depends on how DNS is configured and maintained in your situation.

Comment: nsloookup is no longer maintained and its authors recommend dig. Besides, dig -x is much simpler than inversing the bytes yourself.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks a lot for the input!  Old habits die hard ;)

Answer (score 2):

Powershell:

```
[net.dns]::gethostentry("69.59.196.212").HostName
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the command-line dig for Windows (available here: http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/) to nslookup any day.

If you have to test/administer DNS from a Windows workstation, grab this tool. Then:

```
C:\dig>dig -x <IP Address>
```

...also, remember to add c:\dig to your path!

Answer (score 0):

Well, some friendly person just wrote nslookup is the command, and he's right. It works on both Unix and Windows.  Not sure why you deleted your answer, but you are correct sir.

Comment: err, maybe not.

Comment: Yeah well, I did post a bit fast, and after a check I wasn't sure at all of my answer, I just put back my post and edit it to add more details ;)

Comment: OK, it is, but it isn't I'm accepting that answer.  Too bad we can't get that real time Googley AJAX here.

Comment: lol yeah well, we can't have everything ;) Have a nice day, I hope I help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some command line tools for reverse DNS:

1. **Dig:**

`dig -x [IP Address]`

2. **Nslookup:**

`nslookup -type=ptr [IP Address]`

3. **Host:**

`host [IP Address]`

Answer (score 0):

cant leave comment but to install dig on Debian

```
 apt-get install dnsutils -y ;
 address_i_haz=`curl -s http://ipv4.icanhazip.com` ; # use you own pls dont spam them in prod ;)

 dig -x $address_i_haz ;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/568310)

Answer (score -1):

nbtstat -a < ip address >

Comment: nbstat isn't a DNS utility but rather WINS/NetBIOS

Answer (score -1):

Her's my take on a more complete DNS reverse lookup. Hope this will come in handy to future viewers of this page.

```
for ip in {1..254..1}; do dig -x 1.1.1.$ip | grep $ip >> dns.txt; done;
```